# Is it possible to get permissions on android making app with create-react-native-app?

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

Currently, I'm trying to make a simple application which let a user choose a photo from android phone gallery and send it to server
I started with create-react-native-app and watch my app in Expo on a physical android phone. Now I struggle to get permission to Android device's gallery but have no luck
Is it possible to get permissions in the app being developed with create-react-native-app at all?

Answer (score 1):

While working with `create-react-native-app` some default react-native api's not work, for example this `android-permissions` api gives in react-native docs

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

To use default `react-native` api either you have to start project with `react-native init` or you have to eject your project. For more info about `ejecting` refer this link https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

But because you are working on `create-react-native-app` you have to use `Expo Client Api's` that is available here, https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/sdk/permissions. This will work.

And for more info about `create-react-native-app` api's refer this link, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/

Comment: Thank you, now I know it's impossible

Comment: It's not impossible, just you have to use `create-react-native-app` api's that is available on `Expo` site.

Comment: And is it ok to use its api? I mean once I will finish work on the app and will need to build it. Will I have to replace expo's api with "normal" android permissions in that case?